# Imageresizer : How to fix GhostScript exception when converting PDF to PNG

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ghostscript, imageresizer

When trying to convert PDFs to PNG thumbnails using ImageResizer (3.4.2) as follows:

https://somehost.com/file.pdf?format=png&width=1024&height=1024&autorotate=true

Some PDFs work fine.  Others give exceptions similar to the following:

```
ImageResizer.Plugins.PdfRenderer.Ghostscript.GhostscriptException: <pdf> <fileNameData><value>67</value><value>58</value><value>92</value><value>87</value><value>105</value><value>110</value><value>100</value><value>111</value><value>119</value><value>115</value><value>92</value><value>84</value><value>69</value><value>77</value><value>80</value><value>92</value><value>116</value><value>109</value><value>112</value><value>54</value><value>49</value><value>53</value><value>56</value><value>46</value><value>116</value><value>109</value><value>112</value></fileNameData> <pageCount>1</pageCount> <pages> <page number="1"> <mediaBox height="792" width="612" top="0" left="0"/> Error: /stackunderflow in --dup-- Operand stack: Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1932 1 3 %oparray_pop 1931 1 3 %oparray_pop 1915 1 3 %oparray_pop 1803 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- 2 1 1 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1172/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:84/200(L)-- --dict:84/200(L)-- --dict:109/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:292/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:26/32(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Current file position is 3951

Generated: Fri, 07 Mar 2014 17:14:21 GMT

ImageResizer.Plugins.PdfRenderer.Ghostscript.GhostscriptException: <pdf>
<fileNameData><value>67</value><value>58</value><value>92</value><value>87</value><value>105</value><value>110</value><value>100</value><value>111</value><value>119</value><value>115</value><value>92</value><value>84</value><value>69</value><value>77</value><value>80</value><value>92</value><value>116</value><value>109</value><value>112</value><value>54</value><value>49</value><value>53</value><value>56</value><value>46</value><value>116</value><value>109</value><value>112</value></fileNameData>
<pageCount>1</pageCount>
<pages>
<page number="1">
<mediaBox height="792" width="612" top="0" left="0"/>
Error: /stackunderflow in --dup--
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1932   1   3   %oparray_pop   1931   1   3   %oparray_pop   1915   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1172/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:84/200(L)--   --dict:84/200(L)--   --dict:109/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:292/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:26/32(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 3951

   at ImageResizer.Plugins.PdfRenderer.Ghostscript.GhostscriptEngine.Execute(GhostscriptSettings settings)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.PdfRenderer.PdfRendererPlugin.GetPdfInfo(String path)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.PdfRenderer.PdfRendererPlugin.DecodeStream(Stream s, ResizeSettings settings, String optionalPath)
   at ImageResizer.Resizing.AbstractImageProcessor.DecodeStream(Stream s, ResizeSettings settings, String optionalPath)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.DecodeStream(Stream s, ResizeSettings settings, String optionalPath)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.LoadImage(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean restoreStreamPos)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource, Boolean addFileExtension)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.<>c__DisplayClass3.<HandleRequest>b__2(Stream stream)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.<>c__DisplayClasse.<TryWriteFile>b__d()
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.LockProvider.TryExecute(String key, Int32 timeoutMs, LockCallback success)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.TryWriteFile(CacheResult result, String physicalPath, String relativePath, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, DateTime sourceModifiedUtc, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean recheckFS)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.GetCachedFile(String keyBasis, String extension, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, DateTime sourceModifiedUtc, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean asynchronous)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(HttpContext context, IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString, IVirtualFile vf)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I've tried several different versions of Ghostscript, including the one that Imageresizer automatically downloads as well as the latest version from sourceforge (9.10).

Answer (score 1):

A stackunderflow basically tells you that the PostScript is invalid. In this case the program attempted to copy ('dup') the object on the stack, and clearly there was no object on the stack, hence stackunderflow.

To investigate that I would need a copy of the PDF you are using and the exact command line being passed to Ghostscript. If you can supply both of those, then you should quickly test the problem by executing said command line from the shell, if it still goes wrong then you can open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same error and I downloaded the [sourcecode](http://imageresizing.net/download) of the PdfRenderer plugin. There you will find the PostScript (pdfInfo.ps) file in the ImageResizer.Plugins.PdfRenderer project in the Ghostscript/Resources/ directory.

You can modify this PostScript and leave the following part out:

```
% CropBox
dup /CropBox pget {
  aload pop   % NOTE: Elements are reversed when popping from stack 
  (<cropBox) print 
  ( height=") print =print (") print
  ( width=") print =print (") print
  ( top=") print =print (") print
  ( left=") print =print (") print
  (/>\n) print flush
} if
```

Of course you have to build the project and use the output dll.